# How to wait for S3 Image to load?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

In my react native app with AWS Amplify I use S3 Image to show images from my S3 bucket. I want to know how to display an animation(a gif) till my S3 Images load and after the image has loaded then show the image?

```
<S3Image imgKey={info.Imageurl} style={styles.image}/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/ui/storage/s3-image/q/framework/react/#props-attr-amplify-s3-image) has a `handleOnLoad` attribute that's called when the image loads.

This should work:

```
<S3Image imgKey={info.Imageurl} style={styles.image} handleOnLoad={()=>{console.log('da-ta!'}}/>
```

Note, it appears that you will need to render the S3Image tag to start the image loading. I don't know what it's appearance is while the image is loading, but if you want to show/hide it you should do that via the style attribute and not by including or excluding the component from render with conditional logic like `{isImageLoaded && <S3Image.../>}`.

**EDIT**
The above is wrong, per @sama that attribute is not available for React Native. You could get a link to the image and then include that in an `<img src={imageUrl}>` tag. Probably make your own component that takes a component to display as the loading state and the `key` of the object in S3.

The default config for `Storage.get` has `download = false` so you'll get a signed-url that points the the image object in the S3 bucket. Your component can show the loading image while it awaits the real image's url, then plug that into an image tag. You'll still need to wait on the image tag to actually fetch the image, so keep it hidden until you get the image's onload event, then set set the image to visible and hide your spinner.

`const signedURL = await Storage.get(key)`

Comment: I think 'handleOnLoad' is found in '<AmplifyS3Image />' which is used in react applications.  I tried it in '<S3Image />' but it doesn't work.